# What is the matrix representation of Radon transform?

Tags: matrices, image-processing

Just as the title, my question is what is the matrix representation of Radon transform (Radon projection matrix)? I want to have an exact matrix for the Radon transformation.

(I want to implement some electron tomography algorithms by myself so I need to use the matrix representation of the Radon transformation.)

(An introduction of the Radon transformation: [click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform).)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I was looking for the same answer. You can see that thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166562/radon-transform-matrix-representation). However, I don't think my solution is the only way to do it nor necessarily the best way.

We know it's a linear transform, so if you can take the transform of the right identity matrix, you'll get the matrix representation. As an easy example using matlab notation, if we wanted to get the matrix representation of a column-wise DFT matrix using the `fft()` function, we could do it with `A = fft(eye(N))`. Now, it's a little more complicated with the radon transform to do it efficiently, but the same idea applies.

If the image is $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$ and we wanted to find the DRT matrix $\mathbf{R} : \mathbb{C}^{M \times N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{L\times P}$, then we know that $\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{C}^{LP \times MN}$ and that the DRT is given by $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{R} \cdot \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{X}) \in \mathbb{C}^{LP \times 1}$, where $\operatorname{vec} : \mathbb{C}^{A\times B} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{AB \times 1}$. The typical 2-D display of the DRT would then be had by simply reshaping the $LP \times 1$ vector into a $L \times P$ array.

We don't know $\mathbf{R}$, but we have access to a function that will efficiently compute the DRT, call it `radon()`, such that `Y = radon(X)` is equivalent to $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{R} \cdot \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{X})$. Since $\mathbf{R} \cdot \mathbf{I} \cdot \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{R} \cdot \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{X})$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix, if we can used `radon()` in such a way that `A = radon(I)`, then we have that `A * vec(X) = radon(X)`.

The problem is that I don't see how to use `radon` to efficiently compute the above. Most `radon()` implementations take a 2-D input and output a 2-D array. It's simple enough to reshape the input/output into vectors, but the problem is that you would have to do that $MN$ times. Even for modest image sizes, the above will become computationaly prohibitive rather fast.

I hope the above helps. If you come up with an efficient solution, please post it here or at the stackoverlow thread linked above.

Comment: So what abut the answer you gave yourself on the thread you posted several years ago? Is it a good solution for find the Radon?

Comment: For that thread and the answer, the Matlab code you gave, what is `(ceil(-M/2) : floor(M/2)-1)` and `(ceil(-M/2) : floor(M/2))`? Why in parenthesis? There is no Matlab expressions like that... What is the imggrid function exactly? I still don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Ian It worked from what I remember. I'm not sure what the confusion about the matlab syntax is; it's perfectly valid. However, I added the contents of `imggrid` to my answer in that post. Hopefully that will clear things up.

Comment: Does radon matrix just have value 0 and 1? Like the output of your code. Why?

Comment: @Ian Because all it is doing is summing a certain set of pixels together. Each output pixel in the radon transform is the sum of the pixels that lie along a certain line. To calculate this sum, we weight the pixels along this line by $1$ and those that don't by $0$, then we sum the weighted pixels together.

Comment: In theory and following the definition of DRT, should the matrix representation of Radon just have value 0 or 1? Or is it just your estimation for your code? Because according to the definition of DRT I don't see why it's just 0 and 1.

Comment: @Ian All each matrix row does is choose which pixels to sum. These pixels will all lie along the line represented by that row. Unless you want to include an interpolation step prior to the summation, then yes, it will only have entries of zero and one. It would be entirely doable to work a bilinear interpolation into the matrix if you wanted to. Rather than grabbing and summing the nearest pixels to the line like I did, the interpolation could interpolate at intervals of $\mathrm{d}s$ using the nearest four pixels to each point. That, however, was more work than I wanted to put into it.

Comment: Can you favorably leave me your email address or sth.? I am reading your code in the answer for the other thread and get confused at some places. So I can ask you more easily. Thanks!

Comment: Let me put my main questions here regarding the codes you gave in the other thread. 1) why you chose `rho = -W/2 : drho : W/2`? Why `-W/2` and `W/2`? 2)what do you mean by "We chose which one based on angle so that we never get close to dividing by zero."? and why you consider two cases `phi >= pi/4 && phi <= 3*pi/4` and others? I think I don't quite understand here.

Comment: 3) What your purpose for this part for each line? `for jj = 1 : L
      p = round( tn(jj,:) - min( nimg ) ) + 1;
      q = round( mline(jj,:) - min( mimg ) ) + 1;  
      inds = p >= 1 & p <= N & q >= 1 & q <= M;
      R( (ii-1)*L + jj, unique( sub2ind( [ M N ], q(inds), p(inds) ) ) ) = 1;
    end`? Can you explain more explicitly or add more comments on the code? Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 1):

Radon transform consists in a rotation plus a projection in X axis.

This code will throw True for any squared matrix where there is an inscribed circle containing the target values.

```
from skimage.transform import radon, rotate
import numpy as np


def get_image_center(img):

    center = (img.shape[0] * 0.5, img.shape[1] * 0.5)

    return center

def rotate_image(img, deg):

    rotated_img = rotate(img, 
                         deg, 
                         center=get_image_center(img), 
                         preserve_range=True)

    return rotated_img

theta_test = np.linspace(0, 360, 100)

sinogram = radon(image, theta=theta_test, circle=True)

def perform_radon(img, angle_vector):

    radon_result_list = []
    x_projection_matrix = np.ones(img.shape[0])

    for angle in angle_vector:
        rotated_img = rotate_image(img,  - angle)
        radon_transform = np.dot(x_projection_matrix, rotated_img)
        radon_result_list.append(radon_transform)

    arr = np.vstack(radon_result_list).T

    return arr

manual_radon = perform_radon(img, theta_test)
manual_radon.shape

np.allclose(manual_radon, sinogram)
```

The last thing needed to get a linear transformation that represents Radon transformation is to get a linear operator that represents the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am solving the same problem as you guys.
I found a way to find the matrix.

First, we may view image(MxN) as a vector by certain reshape.
Second, set the ONLY one entry to 1, and others to 0.
Third, input this image to the function 'radon' then you way get the transformed image(LxP)

Loop over these three steps for every entry of image, which may causes MxN times.
cascade the result image(LxP) MxN times, then you will get the answer.

```
I.e. for 2x3-->3x4
[1 0 0 0 0 0]-->X_1 (reshape to a row vector)
[0 1 0 0 0 0]-->X_2 (reshape to a row vector)
[0 0 1 0 0 0]-->X_3 (reshape to a row vector)
[0 0 0 1 0 0]-->X_4 (reshape to a row vector)
[0 0 0 0 1 0]-->X_5 (reshape to a row vector)
[0 0 0 0 0 1]-->X_6 (reshape to a row vector)

Finally, stack result row vectors
[X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6].T
```